# Ionic Angular TypeError: architect_1.createBuilder is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

When I try to compile application by `ionic cordova build android` i throw this error. I'am using a latest version of Angular and Ionic 4. I was trying to update angular@cli, angular@core and @ionic/angular-toolkit

````
TypeError: architect_1.createBuilder is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Apps\Pojazdy\node_modules\@ionic\angular-toolkit\builders\cordova-build\index.js:17:31)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Promise.resolve.then (D:\Apps\Pojazdy\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js:80:61)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.```
````

Answer (score 24):

I had a same problem.

I found this link https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-angular-8/167535/5 where was mentioned other link of google drive: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QOpQeDifPSg6F9WycDLcbQnpqjN96ew-Ap0_CB7CcCQ/edit

I executed this command and it worked for me:

```
npm i @angular-devkit/architect@latest @angular-devkit/build-angular@latest @angular-devkit/core@latest @angular-devkit/schematics@latest
```

Tks!

Comment: I was trying the ng add @angular/fire command on an angular prj and failed . This solved it.